# How can I parse or scrape the email from this HTML using selenium or beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

How can I parse the second a tag from this div section. When I tried it always select the first one from the div children. How can I select the second so I can get the email.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  Address:
  <div style="padding-left: 1em">
    Box 460
    <br />
    <a href="/canada/Clinton-Village.html"
      >100 Mile House, British Columbia V0K 2E0</a
    >
  </div>
  <br /><b>Enrollment:</b> 310<br />
  <b>Grade span:</b> K-7<br />
  <br /><b>School Type:</b> Standard School<br />
  <b>School Category:</b> Public School<br />
  <br /><b>Principal:</b> Mrs Donna Rodger<br />
  <b>Phone (verify before using):</b> (250) 395-2258<br />
  <b>Fax (verify before using):</b> (250) 395-3621<br />
  <b>E-mail:</b>

  <a href="mailto:donna.rodger@sd27.bc.ca">donna.rodger@sd27.bc.ca</a>
  <br />
</div>
```

I tried using Xpath

```
        emailElement = email_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main_body"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
        result_email = emailElement.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
        print(result_email.text)
```

**Output**

**`100 Mile House, British Columbia V0K 2E0`**

It keeps giving me the first  tag. And I want to select select second  tag

Expected output

**donna.rodger@sd27.bc.ca**

I want to parse this section

**`<a href="mailto:donna.rodger@sd27.bc.ca">donna.rodger@sd27.bc.ca</a>`**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```py
emailElement = email_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main_body"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
result_email = emailElement.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
print(result_email.text)
```

Try this:

```py
emailElement = email_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main_body"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
result_email = emailElement.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@href,'mailto')]")
print(result_email.text)
```

You should also improve the `'//*[@id="main_body"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]'` XPath expression, but I can't help there since you didn't share details about that.
You also possibly will have to use `WebDriverWait` expected conditions to wait for element presence or visibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can identify the element

**Option 1:** Find the tag which contains E-mail text and then find next sibling anchor tag

```
print(email_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//b[text()='E-mail:']/following-sibling::a[1]").text)
```

**Option 2:** Find the tag which contains E-mail text and then find next anchor tag

```
print(email_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//b[text()='E-mail:']/following::a[1]").text)
```

**Option 3:** Find the anchor tag, href starts-with() mailto

```
print(email_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href,'mailto')]").text)
```

**Option 4:** Find the anchor tag, href starts-with(^ in css selector) mailto

```
print(email_driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='mailto']").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with cssSelector/xpath instead of tagName.

```
cssSelector : By.cssSelector("a[href*='mailto:']")
or
xpath : By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-4']/a[contains(@href,'mailto')]")
```